# Python Multiprocessing for Docker Requests to Get Distance

Tags: python, docker, distance, osrm

I am using OSRM backend with Docker to get distance between two places. It works fine, I don't have any problem here. However, it takes too long as my table has many rows(approx. 200k rows,30 minutes) and my row count will get bigger. I tried a few things to speed it up.

I changed mld algorithm to ch algorithm like here:

```
docker run --name tr_osrm -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v c:/osrm_tr:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm ch /data/turkey-latest.osrm
```

It speed up a little but not enough.

I gave threads parameter like here:

```
docker run --name tr_osrm -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v c:/osrm_tr:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm ch --threads=8 /data/turkey-latest.osrm
```

The running time didn't change.

I tried multiprocessing in Python to send request to Docker:

```
def osrm_distance(index):
    tmp_df = df_order.loc[index]
    from_lat, from_lon = tmp_df['customer_coords'].split(',')[0],tmp_df['customer_coords'].split(',')[1]
    to_lat, to_lon = tmp_df['store_coords'].split(',')[0],tmp_df['store_coords'].split(',')[1]
    from_ = {'lat':from_lat,'lon':from_lon}
    to_ = {'lat':to_lat,'lon':to_lon}
    
    url = f"""http://127.0.0.1:5002/route/v1/driving/{from_["lat"]},{from_["lon"]};{to_["lat"]},{to_["lon"]}?overview=false&alternatives=false"""
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        res = r.json()
        di = (res['routes'][0]['distance'])/1000
        dur = (res['routes'][0]['duration'])/60
    except:
        r.status_code =! 200
        di= -1    
    
    return pd.DataFrame({'index_no':[index],
                         'distance':[di]})

distances = []
if __name__=="__main__":
    available_cpu = os.cpu_count() - 1
    loop_lst = list(df_order.index)
    with Pool(available_cpu) as p:
        distances.append(p.map(osrm_distance, loop_lst))
        
distances = pd.concat(distances[0], ignore_index=True)
```

The osrm_distance function on the above is working well alone but when I use multiprocessing-pool I got this error and it doesn't send request to Docker:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

Is there any way to get response from Docker faster for big data? Like reducing the time to one fourth or more :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A. If you only need distance and time, as per your python code, then you may want to use OSRM Table api endpoint as opposed to routing.

B. If you need the road geometry.
The bottleneck here is CPU, especially if you are running the docker image on a single machine, albeit the one you're also running the python script on.

Solution 1: Distributed OSRM.
Here's what I, first, did when faced with a very similar issue (1M+ requests).

1. Create a docker-compose file for the osrm service.
2. Run as many replicates of the osrm services as you can afford on separate cloud servers. The more cores the less cloud servers you'll need.
3. Update the python script to query the cloud server urls, in batches of 100 reqs at a time.
4. save your data, delete the cloud servers, and don't get billed for what you no longer need.

Rule of thumb: if 6 cores get you 100 reqs/s, 5x 6 core servers will get you  around 480 req/s. You can extrapolate from that.

Solution 2: Speed things up by reducing http overhead.

1. Use the OSRM node bindings, you'll get a lot more reqs/s as it does
   away with the overhead of 1000s of http requests. You'll need javascript for this.

Solution 3: Best setup for speed = Combine 1 and 2 above, and you'll get around 1500+ reqs/s on 300+ km routes on 5x 6 cores machines (That's the only data point I have).

NB: Would be a good idea for the OSRM community add a one-to-many and many-to-many directions to the routing api.

Comment: useful reply, thanks! 
I'd like to know about the point 1.3, so to "query the cloud server in batches of 100 reqs at time".